# How to add items to a table with PHP and MYSQL, NO AJAX

Tags: php

I am wondering how would you build a table where you can add as many items as needed...let's say you have a video rental and a customer wants to rent 3 or 4 movies. In a web app we would pull the customer data, add a rent and then somehow, have a table where each row would be each video the customer is renting.

Without using AJAX, how would you build this table ?  I am thinking that the only way is to reload everything again, like if you have drop downs, load all of the drop downs, select the values if they were selected, then if the add item button is clicked, then add a row with the corresponding inputs, if I hit add item again, I would do the same thing... Is this the right approach ? re-building the drop downs, inputs, etc, every time I go and add a new item to the table ?  I hope this explains what I am thinking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are right. If you don't want to use ajax and more rows are need to be added on user's feedback you have to reload the page and fetch data again for the table.

Comment: I guess that is the intention of the http protocol after all, to be stateless.

Comment: Something on the page needs to reload yes, But there are work arounds.

Answer (score 0):

The only method that comes to mind is a possibly a iframe ?

You can generate the links / anchor via php as the contents for the frames and then have it re-generate on a change / navigation.

Otherwise for what reason do you wish not to use AJAX?

**ALSO ...**

You can have a hidden iframe and grab the contents of that on the onload event and set it to a tables cell content and generate/insert a new row/cell and so on.. Using the iframe as your grabber via anchor links.. Be sure to add something like a nocache variable to keep the content fresh.

**HTML PAGE CONTENTS index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>iFrame Test</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <iframe name='objGrab' id='objGrabber' style='position:absolute; left:-99999px; top:-99999px;'></iframe>
  <a target="objGrab" href="prc.php?page=1">Page 1</a><br />
  <a target="objGrab" href="prc.php?page=2">Page 2</a>
  <div id='pageContent'></div>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $("#objGrabber").load(function (){
        $("#pageContent").html($(this).contents().find('body').html());
      });
    });
  </script> 
</body>
</html>
```

**PHP PAGE CONTENTS - prc.php**

```
<?php
  switch($_GET['page']) {
    case "1":
      echo "Contents for page one";
      break;
    case "2":
      echo "Contents for page two ";
      break;
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

that would work, but notice somethings.
you should design a database better like

```
TABLE users
 ID - username
TABLE movie
 ID - title
TABLE users_rent_movie
 ID - userID - movieID - rentedOn - returnedOn - status
```

since the movie database isn't supposed to be updated like every minute, once a week or something, and users don't rent every hour a new movie.
Cache the page generated once, and keep using the cached data, until new things are added/changed or an X amount of time has passed, this would make things faster (but if in local, all processes/responses will perform faster).